# Is it possible to measure depth of an image(JPEG/PNG)

Tags: image, image-processing, robotics, camera-calibration, point-cloud-library

I am wondering there must be a way to get a depth of image. Certainly some portions can be extruded so that we get 3d version of 2d image. Any sources that will help in this out.

FYI: I would like to get point cloud from 2d image.
Thank you in advance..

Comment: This is an extremely broad topic and out-of-scope for StackOverflow. This site is about answering specific questions to programming issues.

Comment: This is basically the entire field of computer vision. From a single 2D image this is an extremely difficult problem in general. If you have two or more images take from different vantage points this makes the problem easier. Do some research on computer stereo vision.

Comment: In order to get any kind of depth buffer you could use stereo disparity and will need at least 2 images from two different positions. The general idea is to find pair of spots on both images and see how much their position differ horizontally. Bigger the difference closer they are to the camera. Note that with only one eye or camera you cannot distinguish if the object is very close or is very large but far away. See this http://www.ivs.auckland.ac.nz/quick_stereo/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Reconstruction from single 2D image is not possible. As mentioned by others, there is loads of literature to refer to. Multi-View Geometry by Hartely and Zisserman can be a good start. An example tutorial to start with: [Reconstruction](http://vgl-ait.org/cvwiki/doku.php?id=matlab:tutorial:3d_reconstruction_with_calibrated_image_sequences). you can also refer to computer vision toolbox from matlab/opencv

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to  draw some 3D information from a 2D image.
There are methods to extract depth infortmation from the blur of a pixel. When a picture is captured, you focus in one place and let remaining portion blur, and hence blur captures  depth. 
See [Make3d](http://cs.stanford.edu/content/make3d) project to startwith. 
Thank you.